# How do I tell if a program is running with admin rights

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac

How do I tell if a particular instance of a program running on Win 7 is running with admin rights?

I tried looking at "properties" from Sysinternals process explorer, but I don't know what exactly to look for.

Comment: I can't remember off-hand if Win7 has it, but in Task Manager in Processes view, if you select the View menu and click Select Columns you should be able to add the column "Elevated" which indicates if the process is running as an admin. If this is right, let me know and I'll add it as an answer

Comment: There is by default a "User Name" column displayed in task manager's Processes tab, so you don't even need to change anything to see who is running the task, just checkmark the box to "show processes from all users".

Comment: @Debra: That’s not an answer. If a user is in the Administrators group (i.e., he is an administrator), he can run some programs with admin rights (“Run as Administrator”) and others without -- and they will all show the same user name.

Comment: @Kevin: Windows 7’s Task Manager has a “User Account Control (UAC) Virtualization” column. It shows possible values of blank, “Enabled”, “Disabled”, and “Not Allowed”. I don’t understand these terms in this context, but it looks like “Not Allowed” applies to processes that are actually running as SYSTEM, and (blank) applies to processes that are running elevated.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7's Task Manager, go to the **Processes** tab.  Then add a column for **User Account Control (UAC) Virtualization***.

For processes running elevated with admin rights, the column will be blank.

Regular processes will be listed as "Disabled".